# How to have spacing between x axis ticks be consistent when a line graph doesn't start at the first x axis tick

Tags: python, matplotlib

Originally I had a single graph on one plot:

```
x1 = [0,1,2,3,10,11]
y1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
ax.plot(x1,y1)
```

But this caused the spacing between x axis label to be inconsistent as shown here:

[image]

To fix that instead I did

```
ax.plot(y1)
ax.set_xticklabels(x1)
```

Which then changed the graph to this (which is what I wanted):

[image]

But now let's say I have another line graph which is `y2 = [2,3,4,5,6,7]` and I want to add this graph to the same plot BUT I want to offset it such that it starts at x = 2 for example.

When I say `ax.plot(y2)` it will start at the default first tick (x=1) and if I say `ax.plot(x2,y2)` the 2nd line graph will have the same issue that Graph1 had.

Basically I want the end result to look like two parallel lines but one of them starts at x = 2. Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you want `ax.plot(y2)` to start at x=2, then the lines will overlap each other. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Or, do you actually want to re-plot `y1`, but have _that_ start at x=2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you say in the question you actually want to plot `y2`, starting at x=2, then the two lines would overlap.

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

ticks = [0,1,2,3,10,11]

y1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y2 = [2,3,4,5,6,7]

x1 = np.arange(1,len(y1)+1,1)
x2 = np.arange(2,len(y2)+2,1)

ax.plot(x1,y1)
ax.plot(x2,y2)

ax.set_xticklabels(ticks)

plt.show()
```

Produces:

[image]

You say in the end that you would like two parallel lines, but with one starting at x = 2. If so, then you can do the same as above, but use `y1` instead:

```
ax.plot(x2,y1)
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Shoot sorry you're right, I didn't intend for them to overlap when I was writing y2 but you're solution is what I wanted, thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you plot y2 over a subset of x1:

```
ax.plot(x1[2:5],y2)
```

of cause y2 would have to have the same length as the subset of x1, which is not the case at the moment. Alternatively you could make a list of x-values for each set of y-values.

Comment: That's what I tried when I did ax.plot(x2,y2) where x2 = [2,3,10,11,12,13] but the line graph was not a straight line, it looked like Graph1, thanks though